# Does the Django localtime template filter work on a local host?

Tags: django, templates, time, timezone

I'm trying to display timezone-aware (I checked) times stored in Django DateTimeFields as the time in the user's timezone. When I use `{{ start_time|localtime }}` in my templates, the times displayed don't change at all, though, and they're not my local times. We seem to have everything else you need to support timezone awareness.

I'm running this locally on a Linux machine (timezone UTC-05:00), and right now the times are output four hours ahead of my actual time. This also happens for our remote host. The admin page indicates that the server time, which is set to UTC, is four hours ahead of my timezone.

I am wondering if running this on localhost is part of the problem, but I don't want to push useless code onto our development server if I can avoid it.

Comment: The docs say it uses the current timezone, which you have to explicitly set if you want it to differ from the default timezone: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone . So that's the first thing I'd check. It shouldn't make any difference whether you're running locally or remotely, in either case the rendering should depend on the stored UTC time and the current timezone when rendering the template.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I misunderstood. I thought this would retrieve the user's timezone without work on the backend, but that's not quite as simple in Django as in other frameworks. It seems you have to actually set the current timezone (described right there in your link) manually.